# How to use Framing with akka websocket

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http

I am new to akka-stream and I am trying to use the Framing.lengthField with websocket https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/Framing.scala

Here is what I have:

```
path("websocket") {
    handleWebSocketMessages(websocketFlow)
} 

def websocketFlow(): Flow[Message, Message, Any] =
Flow.fromGraph(
  GraphDSL.create(Source.actorRef[TestMessage](bufferSize = 10, OverflowStrategy.fail)) {
    implicit builder =>
      source =>

        val binaryMessageDecoder = Framing.lengthField(4, 0, 1024 * 32, ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN)

        val byteStringToMessage = Flow[ByteString].map { bytes =>
          TestMessage.parseFrom(bytes.toArray[Byte])
        }

        val fromWebsocket = builder.add(
          Flow[Message].map {
            case bm: BinaryMessage =>
              bm.dataStream
                .via(binaryMessageDecoder)
                .via(byteStringToMessage)
          }
        )

        val backToWebsocket = builder.add(
          Flow[TestMessage].map {
            case TestMessage(text) =>
              TextMessage(text)
          }
        )

        val actorSink = Sink.actorRef[TestMessage](testActor, PoisonPill)

        import GraphDSL.Implicits._

        fromWebsocket ~> actorSink // This line does not compile

        source ~> backToWebsocket

        FlowShape(fromWebsocket.in, backToWebsocket.out)
  }
)
```

I do not understand the issue here. How can I make this work?

Comment: Can you provide some minimal working example with your issue or better explain your problem?

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Your `fromWebsocket` returns streams, not messages, and your `actorSink` takes messages. For example have to change `map` to `flatMapConcat` (or something similar), depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you, using flatMapConcat solved the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fromWebsocket` flow returns streams, not messages, and your `actorSink` takes messages.

If you want it to compile you have to make sure it returns messages, for example you can change `map` to `flatMapConcat`. This will make sure that the messages returned from the streams are concatenated in a new stream of messages.